# Appending to two dimensional List<string>

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm working on an algorithm that checks if its possible to recreate a word from list of strings (smaller words) and returns all the combinations if the word can be reconstructed, else an empty list.

I found it in one of the lectures about dynamic programming. I got it right till the point where I need to accumulate the result of previously found solutions with the current iteration of loop.

My code returns an List of List of strings where each contains single word that recreates the string. I assume its because my algorithm fails to append the results correctly into the `table`, instead  it overrides it.

Code -

```
        List<string> wordbank = new List<string>() { "purp", "p", "ur", "le", "purpl" };
        string target = "purple";
        Dictionary<int, List<List<string>>> table = new();

        for (int i = 0; i < target.Length + 1; i++)
        {
            table[i] = new();
        }

        table[0] = new ();


        for (int i = 0; i <= target.Length; i++)
        {  
            foreach (var word in wordbank)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (target.Substring(i, word.Length) == word)
                    {
                        var tbd = table[i];
                        tbd = tbd.Append(new List<string> { word }).ToList();
                        foreach (var item in tbd)
                        {
                            table[i + word.Length] = table[i + word.Length].Append(item).ToList();
                        }  
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                    
                }
                    
            }
        }
        foreach (var item in table[target.Length])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("__");
            foreach (var v in item)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(v + " ,");
            }
        }
```

Result - `__ purp , __ p , __ ur , __ p , __ le ,`

Expected Result - `__ purp ,le, __ p, ur, p, le,`

Comment: `tbd.Append(new List<string> { word }).ToList();` how many lists do you possibly need to create?

Comment: The amount of lists depends on  the count of words that can be used to recreate the `target` string, which at maximum is `wordbank.Count()` if the string can be remade with every single one of the words from `wordbank`. My problem is that I want to Append on top of existing list from the previous iterations of the main for loop rather than replace it. I edited my post as i forgot to include how i display data and `Exepcted Result`